# Multiple Where on Laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Can anyone help me fix this code ?

```
public function caritindaklanjut(Request $request){
    $halaman="tindaklayanan";
    $cari = '%'.$request->search.'%';
    $rows=DB::table('keluhans')
    ->select(DB::raw('id,produk,username,masalah,status,id_departemen'))
    ->where('status','=','Pending')
    ->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('produk','like',$cari)
        ->orWhere('username','like',$cari)
        ->orWhere('masalah','like',$cari);
    })->orderby('id','asc')->get();
```

It cant pass $cari into $query and getting error... Please Help :)

Comment: You missed to use $cari variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `use($cari)`:

```
->where(function($query) use($cari) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a "use ($cari)" statement at the anonymous function in the second where():

```
public function caritindaklanjut(Request $request){
    $halaman="tindaklayanan";
    $cari = '%'.$request->search.'%';
    $rows=DB::table('keluhans')
    ->select(DB::raw('id,produk,username,masalah,status,id_departemen'))
    ->where('status','=','Pending')
   ->where(function($query) use ($cari) {
        $query->where('produk','like',$cari)
        ->orWhere('username','like',$cari)
        ->orWhere('masalah','like',$cari);
    })->orderby('id','asc')->get();
```

Comment: why the anonymous in the first place?

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja see my comment to your answer